# Create a font table for all available characters for a particular font

Tags: fonts, xetex, symbols, luatex, context

Similar to the question:

[Lualatex: Font table with examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23630/lualatex-font-table-with-examples)

I have several ornamental fonts and I'd like to create key maps. That is, I want to know what symbol the letter `a` maps to by having a nice table. The problem is, many of these fonts don't include all the characters and I don't know, *a priori*, which ones are included. I'd rather not have a mess of empty boxes filling up the table. Is it possible to iterate through the *valid* characters in a font and just display them? Any (Lua, Con, Xe, La, etc...)-Tex solution is welcome.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

can be done with `luatex`. `\OD` is the font face of the ornament font (needed on TeX level)

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.3cm} \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\newfontface\OD{OrnamentalDecoration.otf}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{4}\noindent
\begin{luacode*}
local f = fontloader.open('OrnamentalDecoration.otf')
local glyphs = {}
for i = 0, f.glyphmax - 1 do
   local g = f.glyphs[i]
   if g then
       table.insert(glyphs, {name = g.name, unicode = g.unicode})
   end
end
table.sort(glyphs, function (a,b) return (a.unicode < b.unicode) end)
for i = 1, #glyphs do
   tex.sprint(glyphs[i].unicode .. ": ")
   if (glyphs[i].unicode > 0) then
       tex.sprint("{\\OD\\char" .. glyphs[i].unicode .. "}");
   end
   tex.print(" {\\small(")
   tex.print(-2, glyphs[i].name )
   tex.sprint(')}\\\\')
end
fontloader.close(f)
\end{luacode*}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just so I understand, the check is in `(glyphs[i].unicode > 0)`? Great work, this is perfect!

Comment: This is much nicer than my code in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98188/how-can-i-access-a-specific-glyph-in-lualatex-fontspec/98224#98224

Comment: @Hooked: and also `if g then ... `

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/666152/256738) is a patched version that can also print out the `-1` glyphs!

Answer (score 9):

In ConTeXt you can use the `fnt-10` module to display a list of the glyphs of
a particular font. See also [my answer to “Accessing font
ornaments”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87563/5245) for a more detailed description of how to use the symbols.

```
\usemodule [fnt-10]
\starttext
    \ShowCompleteFont{name:minionproregular}{10pt}{1}
\stoptext
```

[image: result]