# ConTeXt: How to redefine the euro sign glyph?

Tags: symbols, context, context-mkiv, font-encodings

## Introduction

I am writing a document using the TeX Gyre Pagella font.
Unfortunately, the glyph for the euro sign (UTF-8 character `U+20AC`) in this font
does not comply with [the official euro sign specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aEuro_Construction.svg).

Luckily, the [Martin Vogel symbol font](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Symbols/mvs) does contain a symbol which glyph seems alright.

## Minimum working example

[image: euro glyphs]

```
\setupbodyfontenvironment[default][em=italic]
\usemodule[simplefonts][size=14pt]
\setmainfontfallback[DejaVu Serif][range={greekandcoptic, greekextended}, force=yes, rscale=auto]
\setmainfont[TeX Gyre Pagella]

% Martin Vogel Symbol font for euro sign
\usesymbols[mvs]
%\definesymbol[€][{\symbol[europe][EUR]}]

\starttext
\startitemize[packed]
\item € is the glyph of the TeX Gyre Pagella font.
\item \symbol[europe][EUR]~is the glyph of the Martin Vogel symbol font.
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

## Question

How can I redefine the encoding for `U+20AC` (€) so that it corresponds to the Martin Vogel glyph?

In other words, I am looking for a preamble command so that the first line in the MWE also would show the Martin Vogel symbol glyph.

My commented-out `\definesymbol[€]` attempt did not work...

Comment: How about filing a bug report with the TeX Gyre project?

Comment: Here is an even more detailed account of [the typographical history of the Euro symbol](http://www.fontshop.com/blog/fontmag/002/02_euro/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the Martin Vogel font does not contain the Euro symbol in
the correct slot, so you can't just use a simple font fallback as described in
[this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124852/5245). I don't know if
there's a simple way to map a font fallback to different slots of another font
without messing with virtual fonts.

#### Solution 1

Here is a simple workaround, which just replaces all occurences of “€” with an
instruction to insert a particular glyph from another font. This is not very
robust and might break unexpectedly (for instance in verbatim environments).

```
\usemodule [translate]
\enableinputtranslation

\translateinput
  [€]
  [\getnamedglyphdirect{marvosym.ttf}{EUR}]

\starttext
  €
\stoptext
```

#### Solution 2

Here's a second solution which is more robust than the crude input translation. It uses a regular font fallback and the new simplefonts module which is part of the core as of `2013.09.30 20:05`. The euro sign is taken from the Martin Vogel font. Because the euro sign uses a wrong slot, a font feature is created using a substitution to correct the font slot. The euro sign is taken from the Martin Vogel font, although it does exist in the main font.

```
\startluacode
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name    = "euro",
        type    = "substitution",
        nocheck = true,
        data    = { [0x20AC] = "EUR" },
    }
\stopluacode

\definefontfeature
    [euro]
    [mode=node,
     euro=yes]

\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [serif] [MarVoSym] [range=0x20AC, features=euro, force=yes]
\definefontfamily     [mainface] [serif] [TeX Gyre Pagella]

\setupbodyfont [mainface]

\starttext
    The euro sign (€) is the currency sign used for the euro.
    In Unicode it is encoded at \type{U+20AC €} euro sign.
\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Comment: Are there other fonts which have the right Euro symbol? If so, they may be used as fallbacks.

Comment: @Aditya -- the euro symbol was designed by a committee, a committee that apparently had no input from knowledgeable typographers.  the shape as "designed" is found by font designers to be offensive, as it stands out from the text "background" more than necessary or desirable.  therefore, most fonts do *not* follow the mandated design for the euro, but provide a version compatible with the style of the including font.

Comment: @Marco Your solution is indeed good, but not perfect. Unfortunately, it breaks in the `\type{}` environment. However, I would not mind if it would be left untranslated in that environment. Perhaps you could extend your solution to account for that. That would make it perfect, at least for me.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt That's not possible using my hackish solution. It's like “search and replace” in your editor, just using Lua. When it reaches TeX, is has been substituted already. I have a second hack in mind (using regular fallback + feature file for marvosym to correct the slot), but no time at the moment to update my answer.

Comment: @Aditya Here is snippet of post-modern European history: _"[Typographers discuss the euro](http://www.evertype.com/standards/euro/eurotypo.html)."_ Fascinating...

Comment: @Marco It would be great to have a kind of compartmentalised input translation. That way, one could single out `\type{}`. Just some wishful thinking...

Comment: @Marco Interesting... When I substitute `uni0063` in your code with the correct euro glyph `uni00A4`, I receive `!LuaTeX error (file .../marvosym.ttf): Invalid glyph index (gid 215)`. Why would that happen?

Comment: @SergeStroobandt The font does not have a glyph at index `0x00A4`. I changed the example to use `0x00A7` instead.

Comment: @Marco Mystery solved: I am using ConTeXt Standalone `version: 2014.02.01 14:22` with its own copy of the font in `/opt/context/tex/texmf/fonts/truetype/public/marvosym`. However, I was looking at the glyph chart of the Nov. 2007 version of the font as installed on my Debian GNU/Linux system under `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-marvosym/`. Could it be that the ConTeXt version of the font is outdated or perhaps of Windows origin?

Comment: @Marco According to the [MarVoSym version history](http://www.marvosym.com/history.html), the mapping of the font changed with version 3.10 to accommodate Windows users.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt ConTeXt standalone uses the current version 3.10. The unicode char `U+00A7` is located in the font in slot 164 (decimal) or `0x00A4` (hex).

Comment: @Marco I was not aware that the hex code of the unicode character could differ from the hex code of the font slot. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @SergeStroobandt Welcome to the m̶e̶s̶s̶y̶ beautiful world of fonts! :)

Comment: @Marco Your wonderful solution 2 no longer seems to work with ConTeXt `ver: 2017.05.15`; even when replacing `[MarVoSym]` by `[marvosymwithtexsupport]`. Could you have again a look at this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Marco FYI, ConTeXt documentation now also features [`\usesymbols`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Symbols), including [`[mvs]`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Symbols/mvs#europe). However, none of that seems to be working.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt It's fixed. I also got rid of the external feature file and replaced the glyph slot with the glyph name. Should be working again.

Comment: @Marco I tested it and it works. Many thanks for that! Only in my setup (ConTeXt `version: 2017.05.15 21:48` as included in the Ubuntu repository), I need to replace the font name `[MarVoSym]` by `[MarVoSym with TeX Support]`. Otherwise, I get the main font's Euro sign with the following warning `selectfont      > The name 'marvosym' is not a proper family name, use 'marvosymwithtexsupport' instead.`

Comment: @Marco  I have also deleted my outdated `simplefonts` answer. In my old code I also had `rscale=auto`. I cannot recall what it does. Is this still relevant?

Comment: [The `rscale=...` option ensures that all fonts have the same x-height.](https://www.contextgarden.net/Fonts_in_LuaTeX#Combining_predefined_fonts_in_your_own_typescripts)