# LuaTeX: Print glyphs with codepoint value -1 by name

Tags: luatex, fontspec, luaotfload

## Context

I would like to print a full glyph table for a given font. Glyphs in an open type font can be identified by

1. an optional code point value
2. by a glyph name

Some fonts like `cambriai.ttf` have some glyphs without a codepoint assigned, but they still have a glyph name, for example `uni02E5_uni02E8_uni02E6.ccmp`. Those glyphs get code point value `-1` assigned.

## Problem

How can I print a glyph by *name* and not by code point value, even if the [value is `-1`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644354/256738)?
I'm using the code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98789/256738) with LuaTeX and it works, but clearly for the font above, the glyphs with value -1 are not shown.

[image]

Comment: check the unicodefonttable package https://ctan.org/pkg/unicodefonttable or provide a suitable test document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The code is the exactly same that I linked, only the font name changed to `cambriai.ttf`. With `unicodefonttable` I get a smaller table than with the linked code, because it ignores the `-1` values completely, but that's exactly the interesting ones. Such a table that only works over code point values can't solve the problem of showing all glyphs in a font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now found a solution based on the discussion [here](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/198) that works for my font created with FontLab 8, but not with the example font name `cambriai.ttf`.
Together with the following code, the linked glyph table can be completed to print all glyphs in the font), but as I said, for some reason it does not work with `cambriai.ttf` but with others it works...

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont{my_fontname.otf}
% the following line prints the glyph with the glyph name S_t that has no code point value assigned (codepoint value = -1). It seems that it does not work with cambriai.ttf but with a OTF-font created by FontLab 8 (maybe otf only solution?)
\char\directlua{tex.print(luaotfload.aux.slot_of_name(font.current(), [[S_t]])) }
\end{document}
```

Here is the patched glyph table from the linked answer that is now able to also print glyphs which don't have a codepoint value:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.3cm} \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\newfontface\OD{my_fontname.otf}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{4}\noindent
\begin{luacode*}
local f = fontloader.open('my_fontname.otf')
local glyphs = {}
for i = 0, f.glyphmax - 1 do
   local g = f.glyphs[i]
   if g then
       table.insert(glyphs, {name = g.name, unicode = g.unicode})
   end
end
table.sort(glyphs, function (a,b) return (a.unicode < b.unicode) end)
for i = 1, #glyphs do
   tex.sprint(glyphs[i].unicode .. ": ")
   if (glyphs[i].unicode > 0) then
       tex.sprint("{\\OD\\char" .. glyphs[i].unicode .. "}");
   else
       -- Here the updated code: the first glyph table in LuaTeX printing ALL glyphs in a font!
       tex.sprint("{\\OD\\char\\directlua{tex.print(luaotfload.aux.slot_of_name(font.current(), [[" .. glyphs[i].name .. "]]))}}")
   end
   tex.print(" {\\small(")
   tex.print(-2, glyphs[i].name )
   tex.sprint(')}\\\\')
end
fontloader.close(f)

\end{luacode*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```